# how to display tree structure dynamically using angularjs

Tags: java, html, angularjs

i want to display tree structure dynamically.i am using angularjs and directives but getting json object only.
popupview.js:

```
    app.directive('treeview', function(TreeService,$http) {
     return {
    scope: {
    griddata:'=',
     },
    restrict: 'AE',
    replace: true,
    templateUrl: 'app/partials/treeviewgrid.html',
    compile: function(cElem, cAttrs) {
     return {
    pre:function(scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
    },
post:function(scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
 scope.roleList = scope.griddata;
```

controller.js:

```
 (function(){
     app.controller('myController', function($scope,$http,TreeService){
    $scope.roleList =
[{"roleName":"okm:root","roledId":"okm:root","children":[{"roleName":"my","roledId":"my","children":[{"roleName":"self","roledId":"self","children":[{"roleName":"htmlmenu.html","roledId":"htmlmenu.html","children":[]}]},{"roleName":"100.pdf","roledId":"100.pdf","children":[]},{"roleName":"act.txt","roledId":"act.txt","children":[]}]},{"roleName":"test","roledId":"test","children":[{"roleName":"Administration guide.pdf","roledId":"Administration guide.pdf","children":[]},{"roleName":"Quick Install.pdf","roledId":"Quick Install.pdf","children":[]},{"roleName":"test.docx","roledId":"test.docx","children":[]}]}]}];
      });
    })();

    }
    };
    }
    };
    });
```

tree.html:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html ng-app="myapp">
    <body ng-controller="myController">
    <treeview griddata="roleList"></treeview>
    </body>
    </html>
```

from the above code the out put is:

```
[{"roleName":"okm:root","roledId":"okm:root","children":[{"roleName":"my","roledId":"my","children":[{"roleName":"self","roledId":"self","children":[{"roleName":"htmlmenu.html","roledId":"htmlmenu.html","children":[]}]},{"roleName":"100.pdf","roledId":"100.pdf","children":[]},{"roleName":"act.txt","roledId":"act.txt","children":[]}]},{"roleName":"test","roledId":"test","children":[{"roleName":"Administration guide.pdf","roledId":"Administration guide.pdf","children":[]},{"roleName":"Quick Install.pdf","roledId":"Quick Install.pdf","children":[]},{"roleName":"test.docx","roledId":"test.docx","children":[]}]}]}];
```

but expected out put is:

okm:
root
   my
    self
      htmlmenu.html
        100.pdf
         act.txt.

so please provide suggestion for how to do this.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I propose to use some of existing components like this
https://github.com/eu81273/angular.treeview

[image]

example:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['angularTreeview']);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eu81273/8LWUc/